# pythonic way to match dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I have two dictionaries

```
a = {'hola':4.6, 'bye':56.7, 'tres':52.1}
b = {'hola':7.1, 'tres':103.1}
```

and b is a subset of a.

I would like to create a new dictionary, c with values, a/b, i.e.,

```
c = {'hola'=7.1/4.6, 'tres':103.1/52.1}
```

I could do a for loop of elements of b to a, and create the new one, but is there a more elegant way, without looping?  just curious.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Most pythonic is probably dict comprehension:

```
c = {k: a[k]/v for k,v in b.iteritems()}
```

Dict comprehension was introduced in Python 2.7, for older versions use this:

```
c = dict((k, a[k]/v) for k,v in b.iteritems())
```

Comment: Note: in Python 3.x `iteritems` should be changed to `items`.